# MATLAB To File block eval capability

Tags: matlab, simulink

Simulink's [`To File` block](http://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tofile.html) does not have the ability to evaluate a workspace variable to specify the `filename` parameter. How can I have the block take a variable as the `filename` parameter so I do not have to input/adjust it manually?

[image: parameters]

Comment: I do not have Simulink on this machine to test, [this MATLAB Central post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/98195-how-can-i-have-the-to-file-block-use-the-file-name-from-a-workspace-variable-in-simulink-6-5-r2006b) might be useful.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. That solution resolved it rather simply.That is one solution that only a MATLAB expert can think of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've really got 2 choices:

1. If you're doing things programmatically then you could use `set_param` to put a different file name into the appropriate dialog each time you need to change it.
2. You can put a Mask on top of the To File block.  This will allow you to specify a variable in the mask, and its value would get passed down to the actual block.

Comment: 1. I used to do this with a naming scheme based on the blocks name. However, this fell apart when I tried 'Model Referencing'.                                         2. This is the same as the above solution and it works great! Thanks.